# Implement Container in c++

Tags: c++, containers

i want to implement a container, which contains maximal 20 Solutions. 
If the container contains 20 Solutions any Solution that is added is only accepted if its

1) new_value < worst value in the Container

2) if new_value is already in the container (and 1) holds) then memcmp(new_assignment, assigment, assignment_size) != 0

Then the worst solutions is deleted. (Including the int array)
the assignment_size is for all Solutions the same.

```
struct Solution {
  double value;
  int *assignment;
  int assigment_size;
};
```

What is the easiest way to implement this structure? Can you use some container of the STL?

Comment: You can use std::list as container. It's your exercise not our !

Comment: You may check what `std::vector` offers ...

Comment: @double_g Why `std::list`??

Comment: I thought `std::vector` at first as well, but then it occurs to me that `std::map` might fit this better.  `boost::flat_map` if you want performance.  It's very nearly _designed_ for this.

Comment: I suggest a std::list but any sorted containers could be used. I choose a list to keep logic of insertion/poping element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Thank you.
I hope it is correct. It tried to keep the list trough insert sorted so it is easier to check and then you can remove the last element.

```
struct Solution {
  double power_peak;
  int *assignment;
  int size;
  ~Solution() { delete[] assignment; }
};


class Container {
  list<Solution> Solutions;
  uint max_size;
  double worst_solution;
public:
  Container (uint size)
  {
    max_size = size;
  }
  void addSolution(Solution s)
  {
    list<Solution>::iterator insert_position = Solutions.begin();
    while (insert_position != Solutions.end() && (*insert_position).power_peak < s.power_peak)
    {
      if ((*insert_position).power_peak == s.power_peak && memcmp((*insert_position).assignment, s.assignment, s.size) == 0)
      {
        return;
      }
      ++insert_position;
    }
    Solutions.insert(insert_position, s);
    if (Solutions.size() > max_size)
    {
      Solutions.pop_back();
    }
    worst_solution = (*(--(Solutions.end())))->power_peak;
  }
  double getWorst()
  {
    return worst_solution;
  }
};
```

Comment: You either speculated wildly or have inside information, I can't tell which

Comment: Could you explain some more?

Comment: You have renamed `value` to `power_peak`, and made the `worst_solution` publicly available but no other solutions.  I don't see why you did either of those things.

Comment: that don't matter if the name is value or power_peak. i included the worst_solution method to check fast if it is worth to try to insert the Solution.

Comment: @user3680510 Your code has undefined behavior.  Your `Solution` object cannot be copied safely due to missing user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator (read up on "the rule of 3").  If you quit using pointers and used `std::vector` within the `Solution` object, then these issues would go away.

Comment: if i make a list<Solution*> and addSolution(Solution *s) would this also work?

Comment: @user3680510 - `if i make a list<Solution*> and addSolution(Solution *s) would this also work?` Why are you looking for a problem to a solution?  Just use `std::vector<int> assignment` instead of `int* assignment` and all those problems go away.  Making more code use pointers makes the code more fragile.

Comment: `struct Solution { std::vector<int> assignment; double power_peak; };` is all you need.  Not only does this remove the issue of not being safely copyable, you don't need the `size` member since a vector knows it's size by calling the `vector::size` function.

Comment: ok but i still don't understand why array don't know its size but when you call delete[] array the delete knows the size of the array

Comment: @user3680510 - You need to understand that the way you wrote the `Solution` class makes it unsuitable to be stored in a container such as `std::list`.  It has nothing to do with what `delete[]` can or cannot do.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three  Make the changes I suggested, and all of those issues disappear.

Comment: @user3680510: It's always irked me that `delete[]` knows the size of the array, and also how many bytes of memory there are, but there's no way for us to get either piece of information.  Nobody understands why.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I assumed that your solution is described by the `Solution` structure you posted.

The easiest solution would be a `std::array<Solution, 20>`, wrapped in a custom container wrapper.

You should have something like this:

```
class SolutionsSequence
{
public:
    // in a function to add a solution to the sequence, you should
    // implement the criteria to decide which solution is worse
private:
    std::array<Solution, 20> solutions_;
};
```

Other than that, you should not use `memcpy` in C++. Consider using `std::copy`, or `std::copy_n` instead.

Also consider using a `std::vector` for assignments, and then you can get rid of the `assignment_size`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `array`, because `array` is designed for 20 at all times, whereas he has a requirement for _up to 20_, which is a very different thing.